# CSS Button Animation Not Starting

Tags: css, animation, css-animations, keyframe

I'm creating a basic css animation for a restart button. The button is basically going to shrink and grow infinitely. It's for a rock paper scissor game. I'm only going to put the relevant code here. Idk why the animation isn't working. Take a look at the html and CSS code.

```
<div id="gameOver" class="gameOver">
        <p id="finalResult">Game Over! You Lost/Won</p>
        <button id="restartButton">Restart</button>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#restartButton {
    width: 17%;
    height: 100px;
    cursor: pointer;
    color:rgb(255, 197, 249);
    font-size: 3.5em;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 5px;
    border-color: white;
    background-color: rgb(42, 40, 40);
    border-radius: 35px;
    transition: 0.4s;
    animation-name: example 5s infinite;
}

@keyframes example {
    from {height: 100px; width: 17%;}
    to {height: 80px; width: 14%;}
  }

#restartButton:hover {
    transition: 0.4s;
    border-radius: 75px;
    color: rgb(42, 40, 40);
    background-color: rgb(255, 197, 249);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`animation-name` only sets the name of the animation. `animation` is a shorthand for several properties.

```css
#restartButton {
  width: 17%;
  height: 100px;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: rgb(255, 197, 249);
  font-size: 3.5em;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-color: white;
  background-color: rgb(42, 40, 40);
  border-radius: 35px;
  transition: 0.4s;
  animation: example 5s infinite;
}

@keyframes example {
  from {
    height: 100px;
    width: 17%;
  }
  to {
    height: 80px;
    width: 14%;
  }
}

#restartButton:hover {
  transition: 0.4s;
  border-radius: 75px;
  color: rgb(42, 40, 40);
  background-color: rgb(255, 197, 249);
}
```

```html
<div id="gameOver" class="gameOver">
  <p id="finalResult">Game Over! You Lost/Won</p>
  <button id="restartButton">Restart</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
#restartButton {
    width: 17%;
    height: 100px;
    cursor: pointer;
    color:rgb(255, 197, 249);
    font-size: 3.5em;
    border-style: solid;
        display:block;
    border-width: 5px;
    border-color: white;
    background-color: rgb(42, 40, 40);
    border-radius: 35px;
    transition: 0.4s;
  transition-property: transform;
     transform: scale(1);
        transition: 0.4s all ease-in-out;

}


#restartButton:hover {
    border-radius: 75px;
    color: rgb(42, 40, 40);
    background-color: rgb(255, 197, 249);
     animation: example 5s infinite;
        
}

@keyframes example {
  from {
  transform: scale(.7);
  
  }
  to {
    transform: scale(20);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="gameOver" class="gameOver">
        <p id="finalResult">Game Over! You Lost/Won</p>
        <button id="restartButton">Restart</button>
</div>
```